# scraping data from facebook given the geographic location in python

Tags: python, facebook, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a python script to extract data from facebook given a geographic coordinates. In particular I would like to collect the json data of all the people posting in the given location and in a specific period.

I'm having some problems collecting the information because facebook API is denying the access to some information I need from April 2018.

If anyone has any ideas on how to get around this, I would be extremely grateful. Thank you!

Comment: How are you using the API? Please provide the code you've written this far.

Comment: "data of all the people posting in the given location and in a specific period" - that is impossible. you can only get data of users who specifically authorized your app. if they didn´t, the data is none of your business and not available with the api. scraping is not allowed on facebook btw.

Comment: Hi @luschn, I am interested in similar venture. However, what if it is public post? Can you/anyone add some info around this?

Comment: public or not, data of users is none of your business and cannot be gained, without the explicit authorization of the users.